# Why aren't my Unity Game's ui elements working on Google Play store?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-ui

I added some ui elements to my game and they work properly in unity and on my device when connected to unity remote.

But I uploaded it to google play, downloaded it, and some text doesn't appear, buttons aren't pressable, and the background is red for some reason (supposed to be blue). Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

It may be a ratio problem, to fix this use anchors in your UI elements by using the anchor presets or by using the anchor or by using the anchor min and max values in insector, to make it scale with size you can set its UI Scale Mode to Scale With Screen Size.(https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/HOWTO-UIMultiResolution.html). Let me know if that helps

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Please [edit] the answer with all relevant information. Make sure to use your own words, [answers comprised entirely of a quote (sourced or not) will often be deleted since they do not contain any original content.](/help/referencing).